# Finding duplicate rows from Access SQL Table

Tags: sql, select, duplicates

I have a simple database with a table named POTION_INGREDIENTS.

This table have POTION_CODE, INGREDIENTE_CODE AND QUANTITY field to create a recipe.

I want to find common INGREDIENTES for the potion with POTION_CODE equal than C1 and C2.

I was trying the following query but that doesnt works:

```
SELECT
INGREDIENT

FROM 
POTION_INGREDIENTS

WHERE
POTION_CODE='C1' OR
POTION_CODE='C2'

HAVING COUNT(INGREDIENTE) > '1'
```

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT INGREDIENT
FROM   POTION_INGREDIENTS
WHERE  POTION_CODE IN ('C1','C2')
GROUP  BY Ingredient
HAVING COUNT(INGREDIENT) > 1
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: No problem - be mindful of the error message SQL should have spit back at you when attempting to run your initial query.  Basically having count(ingredient) > 1 failed because you can't count specific ingredients for occurrences within the same select statement, without a group by.  Without the group by you would have line items for each ingredient as many times as it had occured in potion_code c1, c2 - but you wanted to only see each ingredient one time with a rollup of the numbers of times that ingredient occurred (your count).  Hopefully that makes some sense :O

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
select    ingredient,
          count(ingredient)
from      potion_ingredients
where     potion_code = 'C1'
          or potion_code = 'C2'
group by  ingredient
having    count(ingredient) > 1
```